# what am i doing wrong? I'm trying to find all of the foods named "Crock Pot Roast"

Tags: mongodb

[image: Picture of database]

I am not able to find the query! I have tried this code, but it is not working

```
db.recipes.find({}, {name:"Crock Pot Roast"})
```

Answer (score 1):

`db.recipes.find({name:"Crock Pot Roast"})` is the query you are looking for.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) first argument to `$find` is the `query` where the 2nd the projection etc.